# JavaScript: End a function early (value returned to another function)

Tags: javascript, return

I'm trying to cancel a function with `return` if `typeof` an prompted input is `!=` to `string`.  That part is easy enough.  But, the only way i've found is to do that from the function that called the returned value.

Is there a way for me to make the `return false` stop the program entirely, other than managing that from the `displayMessage` function?
Hopefully that makes sense.

```
var enterName = function(entered) { 
var currentUser = prompt("Please enter a name"); 
if (typeof currentUser != "string") { 
return false;
}
else { 
return currentUser;
} 
};

var displayMessage = function(currentUser) {
if (currentUser == false) { 
alert("That's not a username"); } 
else {  
var display = alert(`${currentUser} was entered in the first function.`);
return display;
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do all that in one function:

```
var newFunc = function() { 
    var currentUser = prompt("Please enter a name"); 
    if (currentUser == null || currentUser == "") {
        alert("That's not a username"); 
        return false;
    }
    alert(`Proper ${currentUser} was entered.`);
    return currentUser;
};
```